# How to tell my DataGridView what kind of objects it will display in designer

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have a DataGridView in a user control. I can drag a `companies` collection (which is an Entity Collection) to the DGV, which creates a `CompaniesBindingSource` and lets me edit the columns of the DataGridView according to the properties on my `Company` model.

However, I end up setting the `.DataSource` of my DGV in my load event, because I want it to use a `BindingSource` in the parent form.

Since I'm not using the auto-generated BindingSource in my user control, is there a way for my to simply tell my DGV that it will be displaying a list of `Company` models, without having visual studio automatically setting up the `CompaniesBindingSource` in the user control?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you want to achieve. Is this a usercontrol for company-collections only?

Comment: No, I'm using a user control to isolate portions of my UI. It has a company-collections DGV, a contracts-collections DGV, etc. But the main form also has those, and it has the BindingSources for those as well. I want to use the main form's binding sources on the user control, but still use the designer in the user control.

Comment: You could "shadow" some of the properties of the DGW through the UserControl, e.g. the DataSource property.

Comment: Hmm, how would I do that?

Comment: Okay, I did some testing, and yes, no columns are shown. I'll do some more testing and report back to you in some minutes.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I appreciate it. Ideally there'd be a way in the designer to just point to MainForm.CompaniesBindingSource, but no such luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UserControl` create a`DataSource` and a `DataMember` property which reflects those of the `DataGridView`. Then when you drop the control to the form be sure to set *both* properties.

```
<Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", GetType(Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)), MergableProperty(False), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)> _
Public ReadOnly Property Columns() As DataGridViewColumnCollection
    Get
        Return Me.myDataGridView.Columns
    End Get
End Property

<Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataMemberListEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", GetType(Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)), DefaultValue(""), Category("Data")> _
Public Property DataMember() As String
    Get
        Return Me.myDataGridView.DataMember
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.myDataGridView.DataMember = value
    End Set
End Property

<DefaultValue(CStr(Nothing)), Category("Data"), AttributeProvider(GetType(IListSource))> _
Public Property DataSource() As Object
    Get
        Return Me.myDataGridView.DataSource
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        Me.myDataGridView.DataSource = value
    End Set
End Property

<Browsable(False)> _
Public ReadOnly Property Rows As DataGridViewRowCollection
    Get
        Return Me.myDataGridView.Rows
    End Get
End Property
```

Or you can reflect the `DataGridView` itselves.

```
<Category("Controls")> _
Public ReadOnly Property View() As DataGridView
    Get
        Return Me.myDataGridView
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: What are the <Editor...> and <DefaultValue..> lines? They're giving me errors.

Comment: The [EditorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) specifies a design time editor for the property. While the [DefaultValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) tells the designer not serialize the property if it contains the specified default value. Could you say what kind of errors? You may need to import the namespace `System.ComponentModel`.

Comment: It was the import, thanks :) Ok so it works, but I was hoping to be able to edit the DGV from within the user control. I see the columns auto populate in my `MainForm`, but I can't edit them. How can I edit the DGV?

Comment: Np! I've updated the answer and added the `Columns` and `Rows` properties. I think this is the approach you should choose. Just keep reflect properties you need.At [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll find all the info needed.